# "Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am seeing this error (“Uncaught TypeError: $.cookie is not a function”) when I open developer window in chrome for this line of code which is in JavaScript part.

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie('fileDownloadToken');
```

I read some posts in forum which says that we have to include the jquery & cookie src in script tags. But I am completely unaware on how to do it.

1. Can someone please give me a code snippet to resolve this issue ??
2. Also do I have to install some plugin or include some .js script file in my project, if I have to include such lines in script tag ?

Comment: `$.cookie` is not a standard part of jQuery - you need to include the jQuery cookie plugin in your page. https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: How do I install the jquery cookie plugin from that github location ? Do i need to download the .js file from there and include it in my project and use it in the script tags in JS code part ?? I am new to this and debugging already developed application.

Comment: The instructions are in the link. Download the file then add the `<script />` tag as shown.